# jQuery: Move the last items from UL to a new UL

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create the following in jQuery:

I have a list of items (e.g. 10). If the count of the items is more than 6, then copy the remaining items (from 6 to 10) into a new UL to create a drop-down menu structure.

The first version of the menu would be http://jsfiddle.net/ryb7T/ where I have the 10 items.

The result with jQuery should be like: http://jsfiddle.net/hRaWt/ where I have the 1-6 items displayed and the rest of the items, the sub-menu, into a new UL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this jQuery code:

```
if ($("#main-ul li").length > 6) {
    // Too many li
    $("#main-ul")
        .append(
            $('<li>')
            .append('more')
            .append($('<ul>').append($("#main-ul li").slice(5).detach()))
            );
}
```

And live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryb7T/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have more then 6 elements and move it to sub menu which is hidden by default

```
$(function() {
    var $menuItems = $('#menu > li:visible');
    if ($menuItems.length > 6)
    {
        $('#menu > li:gt(5):not(#submenu)').appendTo('#submenu ul');
        $('#submenu').css('display', 'inline');
    }
});
​
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/hRaWt/1/